# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataSet'

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I am trying to create a thumbnail for an image and display that thumbnail in a DataGrid. I did something similar before but this code is a bit different and I am getting this error on the foreach:

> Error 2185    foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Data.DataSet' because 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a
>   public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
 protected void LoadVehicle(string Reg)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["type"] == "vehicle")
        {
            int vehCount = 1;
            DataSet veh = DataUtils.GetVehicleFromReg(Company.Current.CompanyID, Reg);
            foreach (Vehicle vehicle in veh)
            {
                tabsPOD.Controls.Add(GetDivVehicle(vehCount, vehicle));
                vehCount++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I was trying to copy this similar code:

```
protected void LoadDockets(int JobID)
    {
if (Request.QueryString["type"] == "dbrief")
        {
            int DbriefCount = 1;

            List<JobPieceSerialNo> Serials = JobPieceSerialNo.GetJobPieceSerialsByJob(JobID);
            foreach (JobPieceSerialNo serNo in Serials)
            {
                tabsPOD.Controls.Add(GetDivDbrief(DbriefCount, serNo));
                DbriefCount++;
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is GetVehicleFromReg is saved in a file called DataUtilies but then all the properties for the vehicles is saved in a class file called Vehicles.

Comment: what is return type of GetVehicleFromReg?? you can only use IEnumerable objects in foreach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is, that dataset represents whole data, with tables and rows.
You could not iterate it. You could iterate all tables:

```
foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
```

and than even all rows in the table:

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
```

If i could assume that you do have only one table in your dataset, so you could write something like:

```
foreach(DataRow row in veh.Tables[0].Rows)
```

but id depens on what exact data structure your dataset has.

Comment: This did the job for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A DataSet is a container of Tables. So you can enumerate `myDataSet.Tables`. This is a `DataTableCollection`.

See also MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

A dataset consists of a list of tables. Each table then contains a list of rows. So you cannot simply do a foreach on the dataset. Instead you need to loop through each table and for each table loop through each row. Below is a generic working example on how to loop through all the rows in all of the tables of a dataset.

```
private void PrintRows(DataSet dataSet)
{
    // For each table in the DataSet, print the row values. 
    foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Source:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can only use object of types which inherits from IEnumerable in foreach loop. IEnumerable has GetEnumrator() method which is used to iterate through elements.
Foreach internally calls this GetEnumerator to iterate through elements.That is what error states. 
DataSet has Tables properties which you can use to iterate....

```
foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
```